# Sorting queryset with date

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Extending from the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34307663/django-sort-the-query-elements-in-a-weekly-monthly-daily-fashion/34310443#34310443), where queryset is filtered using input from the user, I wanted to know if it was possible to filter queryset depending on present month and week. Eg each month should start on the 1st and each week on a monday and the queryset should be filtered for all the tests that have taken place in the present month and week.

```
models.py

class City(models.Model):
    city_name=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='',blank=False)

class Person(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=3,default="mr",blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='',blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='',blank=False)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)

class Test(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    test_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='',blank=False)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
```

`views.py`

```
def personlist(request, id):
data = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/cities/' + id + '/persons/').json()
context = RequestContext(request, {
'persons': data['results'],'count': data['count'],
})

return render_to_response('template.html', context)
```

And the related [json](http://pastebin.com/pYLBjrjh)

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668619/django-database-query-how-to-filter-objects-by-date-range) question - one way could be to use

```
startdate = date.today()
enddate = startdate + timedelta(days=6)
Sample.objects.filter(date__range=[startdate, enddate])
```

But wouldn't `date.today()` keep changing everyday and thus everyday a new week will start and thus, a new queryset?Similarly with month. Is there a way to get querysets filtered by present week and month. With each starting from every monday and every 1st respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`__month`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#month) and [`__year`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#year) lookups to limit the queryset to this month's objects.

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
this_month_qs = Sample.objects.filter(
    date__month=today.month,
    date_year=today.year,
)
```

To find this weeks objects, you first need to find the date of this Monday. You can do this by finding today's day of the week (Monday = 0, Sunday = 6) using a date's `weekday()` method, and subtracting that many days from today. It's easy to calculate the last day of the week by adding 6 days, and then you can use `__range` to find this week's objects.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
today = date.today()
# Use today.isoweekday() if you want the week
# to start on Sunday instead of Monday 
first_day_of_week = date.today() - timedelta(today.weekday())
end_date = first_day_of_week + timedelta(days=6)
this_week_qs = Sample.objects.filter(date__range=[startdate, enddate])
```

Comment: Doesn't `date.today()` give a string output? How do you get an integer output in terms of weekday?

Comment: As the code shows, you can get the integer day of the week for a date using its `weekday()` method. If you try out `date.today()` in your shell, you can see that it doesn't return a string, it returns a `datetime.date` instance.

Comment: Yes you are right, but subtracting those types throws an error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'int'`

Comment: As you saw in your question, you can use a `timedelta` to add or subtract from dates. I've fixed the code now.